# How to send HTTP protocol from local server in C

Tags: c, sockets, http, network-programming

I have an application which receives commands (http protocol) from its inbuilt web server command menu, running at localhost. I sniffered from wireshark what CGI script sends this webserver to this application (commands like update time, data etc.). I want to build a server locally running only on my PC and want to send the same sniffered commands to this computer application to update the data, time and so on. That means replacing this webserver with my local server. I learned the socket programming on internet and built a server locally, but I am not getting how to send HTTP protocol in C from this server. Because the sniffered CGI script looks like `GET /?action=update_frequency&update_frequency=88 HTTP/1.1`.

I searched on internet but not finding any useful resource. Can anyone please let me know how should I start and proceed.As I am new to network programming, so any suggestions regarding server or http protocol would be welcome.

Thanks much

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for an HTTP library for C to implement a web server, and you want this server to only to requests from localhost? Maybe you could try these:

On Windows, you could use [WinHTTP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384273.aspx).

On *nixes you could look into [libmicrohttpd](http://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/).

Answer (score 0):

the 'GET' protocol is from a web page that used the 'GET' protocol to send the contents of its' user enter-able fields to the server.

So write a web page on the server similar to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>updateFrequency Form</title>
</head>

<body>
<form  id="updateFrequency" name="updateFrequency"  method="get" action="update_frequency">
<label>update_frequency: <input  type="numeric" name="update_frequency"></label>
<input id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and invoke that web page from your local web browser

Since you want to write the actual server, you might want to look at:\

http://www.code2learn.com/2010/12/socket-programming-in-c-server-side.html

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/12/c-socket-programming/

for the details of a simple server implementation.

However, if I were doing it, I would just download/install Apache 2 or Apache 3